# Number of managed accounts allowed exceeded the limit. Please contact Snowflake support

Tags: snowflake-task

[Number of managed accounts allowed exceeded the limit. Please contact Snowflake support.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GubJN.png)

I've created a reader account with my ID as Admin then dropped the reader account, then while creating a new reader account it is giving me exceeded the limit, though I dropped it is not allowing me to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

This is known case at Snowflake side which doesn't let you recreate a managed account even though previous one is dropped. Please contact support@snowflake.com to request for increase in limit of managed accounts.